# how to send notification.userinfo in a notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

In Appdelegate.swift,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("notification", object: nil, **userInfo: notification.userInfo**)
}
```

In ViewController.swift

I included observer and method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"handleNotification", name: "notification", object: nil)
 }

func handleNotification(notification: NSNotification){
    print("enter ")
}
```

When i handle notification, it crashes "unrecognised selector sent to instance"
what is problem?

Comment: You should change `selector:"handleNotification" ` to `selector:"handleNotification:" `

Comment: thanks mishamoix, problem solved with your code

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3**

Change your notification observer to

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleNotification(with:)), name: notification, object: nil)
```

Try to change your handleNotification function to:

```
func handleNotification(with notification: Notification){
    print("enter ");
}
```

Comment: I am using Swift 2.2 in Xcode 7.0. So, #selector is not working

Answer (score 0):

Please add this and check it.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(handleNotification(_:)), name: "notification", object: nil)
```